# How to invoke this webservice method?

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, wsdl

I can't wrap my mind around invoking a simple method of 3rd-party service. Here's the chunk of WSDL for this method:

```
<s:element name="PushRequest">
    <s:complexType>
        <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="LocationCode" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PushRequestXml" type="s:string"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="PassPhrase" type="s:string"/>
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

This is a sample SOAP 1.1 request, generated by web-service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <PushRequest xmlns="http://xxxx.yyyy.com/">
      <LocationCode>string</LocationCode>
      <PushRequestXml>string</PushRequestXml>
      <PassPhrase>string</PassPhrase>
    </PushRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

First I thought that this is one argument of complex type, so I've tried this:

```
ws = CreateObject("webservice", serviceURL);

push = {};
push["LocationCode"] = "xxx";
push["PushRequestXml"] = "yyy";
push["PassPhrase"] = "zzz";

responseXML = ws.PushRequest(push);
```

But got usual CF response `Web service operation PushRequest with parameters {{PushRequestXml={yyy},LocationCode={xxx},PassPhrase={zzz}}} cannot be found.`.

Next I thought that maybe this is not a complex argument (at least it doesn't have a `name` attribute in XML), but three different arguments:

```
ws = CreateObject("webservice", serviceURL);

responseXML = ws.PushRequest(LocationCode = "xxx", PushRequestXml = "yyy", PassPhrase = "zzz");
```

Result is the same: `Web service operation PushRequest with parameters {PushRequestXml={{PushRequestXml, yyy}},LocationCode={{LocationCode, xxx}},PassPhrase={{PassPhrase, zzz}}} cannot be found.`

Any ideas how this should be handled? Please tell if more information needed.

I'm using ACF9, webservice is provided by ASP.net

Thanks.

Comment: have u tried using CFBuilder, and paste in the serviceURL into Services Browser (Show Web Services -> +), and then right click that to generate the correct createObject() call?

Comment: Just a guess, but could the elements ie `LocationCode, PushRequestXml, ..` be arrays? @Henry - I do not use CFB, but that sounds like a cool feature!

Comment: @Henry Thanks for the tip, I don't have CFB (and Windows) but I think I'll find a way.

Comment: @Leigh Well.. that's what I'm trying to find out here :)

Comment: @Henry It proposes this... `ws = CreateObject("webservice", full-service-url);`

Comment: @Sergii - Well .. go ahead and try it ;) ie set push.LocationCode = [ array], etcetera .. Worst that can happen is you get the same error.

Comment: @Sergii, see my answer with screencap

Comment: @Leight Nope, that doesn't help.

Comment: @Sergii - Okay. It was admittedly a guess. But figured it was worth a 5 second test (I did not have CF access at the time.. or I would have just tried it myself ;).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've ended up with using plain POST-ing raw XML to the web-service and parsing response XML manually, as proposed in [this blog post](http://www.mischefamily.com/nathan/index.cfm/2007/2/7/ColdFusion-and-ASPNET-Web-Service-Interoperability-or-Lack-Thereof-Part-II).

Also I've tried wsdl2java as proposed in 3rd part of that blog series, but it did not help me -- method looked exactly as expected previously:

```
public java.lang.String pushRequest(java.lang.String locationCode, java.lang.String pushRequestXml, java.lang.String passPhrase) throws java.rmi.RemoteException;
```

As a result, I haven't found the applicable way for use cfinvoke for my webservice.

So, my current request code looks as follows:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="SOAPXML">
<cfoutput>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <PushRequest xmlns="http://serviceurl.com/">
      <LocationCode>#LocationCode#</LocationCode>
      <PushRequestXml>#XMLFormat(Trim(PushRequestXml))#</PushRequestXml>
      <PassPhrase>#PassPhrase#</PassPhrase>
    </PushRequest>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
</cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>

<cfhttp method="post" url="#ServiceURL#">
    <cfhttpparam type="header" name="SOAPAction" value="http://serviceurl.com/PushRequest" />
    <cfhttpparam type="xml" value="#Trim(SOAPXML)#" />
</cfhttp>
```

Service returns XML, so handling it is not a problem.

Comment: Since it is easily reproducible, I think it'd be best to report to adobe as a bug?  http://cfbugs.adobe.com/cfbugreport/flexbugui/cfbugtracker/main.html

Comment: @Henry I'm not really sure how to describe this problem, plus I'm still not sure that this isn't my error.

Comment: Based on what you posted, *seems* like a basic structure should work. Any chance there is a public wsdl for this web service?

Comment: @Leigh Sorry, but it's a non-public web-service.

Answer (score 0):

Have u tried using CFBuilder, and paste in the serviceURL into Services Browser (Show Web Services -> +), and then right click that to generate the correct createObject() call?

[image: Services Browser in CFBuilder 2]

Comment: Thanks, but as I said in comment, browser gives me absolutely the same code I'm already using, both for cfinvoke and createobject.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no guru on WSDL, but I seem to remember that auto generated WSDL's usually suffix the method with either 'Request' or 'Response', so you may need to simply call 'Push' rather than 'PushRequest'.

```
ws = CreateObject("webservice", serviceURL);

push = {};
push["LocationCode"] = "xxx";
push["PushRequestXml"] = "yyy";
push["PassPhrase"] = "zzz";

responseXML = ws.Push(push);
```

worth a shot.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work either. Plus, provided sample clearly states that method name is `PushRequest`. Thanks for trying, any way.